# HQL query to get all the columns from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I have 2 tables, let's say Table1 and Table2. Both the tables have more than 50 columns. I want to write a query which returns all the columns. After that I will create one model class and map the columns returned from query result which has around 60 columns from both the tables.

Below are the sample columns for 2 tables. I have not made any mappings in entities in java classes.

**Table1**

- id
- search_key
- col3 and so on.. 50+ cols

**Table2**

- id
- t1_id
- col3 and so on.. 50+ cols

I have written one native query as below:

`@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id WHERE t1.search_key IN ('12345')", nativeQuery=true)`

But this native sql query is throwing NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native sql query.

**My Requirement:**

I need to write a query either native or hql which returns all the columns from both the tables based on matching criteria. and then that returned object by query I will map the columns which I want (since I want around 60 columns from both the tables, I don't want to write each column in select statement)

Is there a way to achieve this???

Please let me know if you need more info in question.

Comment: Because it is slightly unclear you just need a query where it joins 2 tables by a value an id for example and show from the joined records all columns from table 1 and table 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I need all the columns from both the tables (i.e. Table1 and Table2). Table2 has 't1_id' column, which refers to 'id' column in Table1. The given query works fine in JDBC, but it is causing issue in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you run your query on a SQL client you can see that it returns all columns (from both tables) so we can understand that the problem is that your query is Associated with an Entity or generally a Java class that **you** have created. If you run your query and save the result on a `List<Object>` and not on a `List<YourCustomObject>` in your code then you will see that every `Object` of your list would contain all rows from both tables. Your SQL query as a plain sql query returns all rows from both tables as it is.

Comment: Yes, I have created corresponding entity classes for both tables and when I run query = "select t1, t2 from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.t1_id and t1.search_key in ('12345')", I get Object array type response which contains 2 objects of t1 and t2. But if I add another search_key. It returns Array of Array which becomes cumbersome for mapping and I could not leverage the potential of hibernate. Is there a workaround where I can achieve List<MyDesiredObject>.

Comment: @anuragtripathi maybe you can create your MyDesiredObject.class to have 2 variables. 1 variable will be T1 object and second variable T2 object.

Comment: Tried this as well but getting error: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type